# How does escaping of mysql execute command with "insert into" work

Tags: mysql, ssh, escaping

The command

```
ssh ionos "mysql --verbose -usam -e 'insert into aladin.products (name,price) values ('\'test\'','\'test\'');'"
```

does work. But why do the escape characters work? Or why does this part:

```
mysql --verbose -usam -e 'insert into aladin.products (name,price) values ('\'test\'','\'test\'');'
```

translate to

```
insert into aladin.products (name,price) values ('test','test')
```

As far as I understand, the interpreter should not be able to make sense of this as I have un-escaped single quotes in the execute string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer of Bill Karwin is correct and should be used for a better readability of the code. It does not answer my question directly though.

Here a more direct answer:

> Enclosing characters in single quotes preserves the literal value of each character within the quotes. A single quote may not occur between single quotes, even when preceded by a backslash.

(https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash)

So the main problem is that `\'` is not interpreted in single quotes. If I try this, I only add a `\` to it and close the string. My code works as it is allowed to glue strings together if there is no space between the characters.

Here a simpler example of my code:

```
mysql 'insert ('\'test\'');'
```

The string after "mysql" is actually `insert (` + `\'` + `test` + `\'` + `);`

This gets interpreted to

```
insert('test');
```

Answer (score 1):

You're dealing with multiple levels of quote interpreters.

1. Your local shell.
2. Your remote shell on the host you ssh to.
3. MySQL's SQL parser.

Each of these layers gets its turn to parse the input and strip one level of quoting. Each layer "sees" the result of the previous layer's quote-stripped string.

Eventually, this becomes confusing. It's hard for a human to predict the format of the string at each level of being stripped.

One way to simplify it is to pipe input to ssh:

```
echo "insert into aladin.products (name,price) values ('test','test');" |
  ssh ionos "mysql --verbose -usam"
```

Then you eliminate most of the layers and nested-quoting problems.